# Python Round not working as expected for some values

Tags: python, function, rounding

In Python 3, I'm trying to round the value **4800.5**, so I was expecting it to **4801**
but it's giving me **4800**. I'm not able to track why this is happening.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done toward the even choice

Comment: @qrsngky you should submit that as an answer

Comment: @jakub My comment explains 'why', but I am guessing that the OP wants an alternative that acts like the `round` of some other languages

Answer (score 3):

That's by design.

If you have a look at `round` function documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) you will find that:

> For the built-in types supporting round(), values are rounded to
> the closest multiple of 10 to the power minus ndigits; if two
> multiples are equally close, rounding is done toward the even choice
> (so, for example, both round(0.5) and round(-0.5) are 0, and
> round(1.5) is 2).

In simple words, `0.5` is a special case which is always rounded toward an even number.

But there're more interesting things. Please have a look at that example:

> The behavior of round() for floats can be surprising: for
> example, round(2.675, 2) gives 2.67 instead of the expected 2.68. This
> is not a bug: it’s a result of the fact that most decimal fractions
> can’t be represented exactly as a float.

What you might want to do is to use Decimal for more conventional rounding logic: https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

For example:

```
>>> Decimal('7.325').quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
Decimal('7.32')
>>> Decimal('7.325').quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_UP)
Decimal('7.33')
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of [ways](https://realpython.com/python-rounding/) to round a number. *round()* behaves according to a *particular rounding strategy* which may or may not be the one you need for a given situation (see the first comment to your question).

If you want to round your number to the upper, you can try this:

```
import math

n = 4800.5
print(math.ceil(n))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP

def round_half_up(decimal_number, places=0):
    if places == 0:
        exp = Decimal('1')
    else:
        exp_str = '0' * places
        exp_str = exp_str[:-1] + '1'
        exp = Decimal('.{}'.format(exp_str))
    return Decimal(decimal_number).quantize(exp, rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)


print(round_half_up(4800.5)) -> 4801
print(round_half_up(4800.555, 2)) -> 4800.56
```

Comment: Thanks, Much for

Answer (score -2):

Round() function will round up to next value, if decimal is >.5
upto .5 it would  round up to  just the integer part.

Comment: This is not true. 0.5 will be rounded to the nearest _even_ integer.